# How to print these results in html unordered list form in stead of xml?

Tags: php, mysql, html, xml, domdocument

I have a php script that takes hierarchical data from a mysql procedure and prints it as xml. I want to these results to be printed as html unordered parent child list. How do I do that. Here is my php script that prints xml:

```
  <?php
      header("Content-type: text/xml");
      $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "********", "spec", 3306);

      // one non-recursive db call to get the message tree !
      $result = $conn->query("call message_hier(1)");

      //--$result = $conn->query("call message_hier_all()");

      $xml = new DomDocument;
      $xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);

      $msgs = $xml->createElement("messages");
      $xml->appendChild($msgs);

      // loop and build the DOM
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       $msg = $xml->createElement("message");
       foreach($row as $col => $val) $msg->setAttribute($col, $val); 

      if(is_null($row["parent_msg_id"])){
        $msgs->appendChild($msg);
       }
      else{
        $qry = sprintf("//*[@msg_id = '%d']", $row["parent_msg_id"]);
        $parent = $xpath->query($qry)->item(0);
        if(!is_null($parent)) $parent->appendChild($msg);
        }
      }
      $result->close();
      $conn->close();
      echo $xml->saveXML();
      ?>
```

this is xml it prints

```
<messages>
    <message msg_id="1" emp_msg="msg 1" parent_msg_id="" parent_msg="" depth="0">
        <message msg_id="2" emp_msg="msg 1-1" parent_msg_id="1" parent_msg="msg 1" depth="1"/>
        <message msg_id="3" emp_msg="msg 1-2" parent_msg_id="1" parent_msg="msg 1" depth="1">
            <message msg_id="4" emp_msg="msg 1-2-1" parent_msg_id="3" parent_msg="msg 1-2" depth="2"/>
            <message msg_id="5" emp_msg="msg 1-2-2" parent_msg_id="3" parent_msg="msg 1-2" depth="2">
                <message msg_id="6" emp_msg="msg 1-2-2-1" parent_msg_id="5" parent_msg="msg 1-2-2" depth="3">
                    <message msg_id="7" emp_msg="msg 1-2-2-1-1" parent_msg_id="6" parent_msg="msg 1-2-2-1" depth="4"/>
                    <message msg_id="8" emp_msg="msg 1-2-2-1-2" parent_msg_id="6" parent_msg="msg 1-2-2-1" depth="4"/>
                </message>
            </message>
        </message>
    </message>
</message
```

Comment: Read about xsl-transformation. For example here: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="messages">
    <html:ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="message" />
    </html:ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="message[message]">
    <html:li>message <xsl:value-of select="@msg_id" /></html:li>
    <html:ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="message" />
    </html:ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="message">
    <html:li>message <xsl:value-of select="@msg_id" /></html:li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="message" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is no attribute `@match` on `xsl:apply-templates`, I belive you wanted `@select`.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, is there no such method that directly generates html representation using DOM representation like saveXML is doing here ?

Comment: You don't *have* any HTML to save. You need to transform it first.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, can you kindly tell how do I use this xslt document into my code, as I have not already used xslt.Soryy for such trivial question.

Comment: First you parse the stylesheet as you would any other document. Then you use `XSLTProcessor` to mash the XML file and XSLT stylesheet together. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php

Comment: Do I need to use these statements of the example given on the link: " $XML->loadXML(my XML document); $xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$XSL = new DOMDocument();
$XSL->load( 'this xsl file', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );
#PRINT print $xslt->transformToXML( $XML );"

Comment: I don't know about the load option and which output format you want, but in general, yes.

Comment: thank you very much, One more thing if you can kindly tell that will output of this php file be final list build in html as it is using both xml & xsl ?

Comment: The XSLT that I give will result in a XHTML fragment. It will still need `<html>` et alia in order to actually be a (X)HTML document.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams , it all went begging. I couldn't use the output of this in my application. As it sends header information & because I need to display output of this file into another file so its not 'possible'. 'Headers already sent error'

Comment: You don't need to send headers, just strip out the namespace.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, oh ok, it starts working as I used Alejandro xsl that was not working yesterday but now it starts and it also don't contain any header so problem solved. thanks again for the help, I will use your & try the way you mention here too as I need to learn all these